# Magento unsetting block by observer

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have an Observer:

```
public function removePrice($observer) {
    // $observer contains data passed from when the event was triggered.
    // You can use this data to manipulate the order data before it's saved.
    // Uncomment the line below to log what is contained here:
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if ($block = $layout->getBlock('catalog_product_price_template')) {
        $layout->unsetBlock('catalog_product_price_template');
    }
}
```

and my config.xml for my observer:

```
...
<controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    <observers>
        <...>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>...</class>
            <method>removePrice</method>
        </...>
    </observers>
</controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
....
```

In my catalog.xml for my shop `app\design\frontend\default\myShop\layout\catalog` the block is defined:

```
<default>
    <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
</default>
```

The Observer is called correctly. The problem is that the block `catalog_product_price_template` still appear in the frontend. Maybe I have the wrong event here?

Would be happy about any answer!:).

Comment: have you tried with `unsetBlock('topLinks')` ?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi tried just now, but the top links (links.phtml) are still there in the FE :[.

Comment: Which block do you want to unset?

Comment: catalog_product_price_template like in the question now. I just tried top links aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bit easier solution. Add the remove element to your XML.

```
public function removePrice($observer) {
    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
    $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<remove name="catalog_product_price_template"/>');              
    $layout->generateXml();
}
```

Another problem could be that your name of your XML block is not correct. Try to remove the block and look if the block is removed. If it's not the correct block then search the block first.

And check our `list.phtml` template. Perhaps there is your price added manually.

Comment: So for the original code by the OP, only the `$layout->generateXml();` was missing in case everything else was correct? (not that your suggestion is better, just asking)

Comment: @hakre I used unsetBlock() instead of ->getUpdate()->addUpdate() which is for some reason not working.